# How do I assign a number to each member of a structure? (swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct, swift2

I have a quiz app. I want the user to be able to press "Next Question" button and be able to access Question 1, Question 2, Question 3 etc. in that order.

I want the app to have a back button so the user can access the previous questions as well. For example if the user is on Question 3 then they can press the back button and access Question 2.

I was thinking of assigning a number to each question in the the question structure and hence calling the Next numbered question or the previous numbered question depending on what button was pressed, i.e. "Next Question" button or the "Previous Question" button.

This is how I have set up my questions:

```
struct  Question {
    var Question : String!
    var Answers : String!
}

var Questions = [Question]()
var QNumber = Int() 


@IBOutlet weak var labelForQuestion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textBoxForAnswer: UITextView!



override func viewDidLoad() {    
    //hiding answer
    textBoxForAnswer.hidden = true

    //Load Questions
    Questions = [

        Question(Question: "This is question 1", Answers: "This is answer 1"),

        Question(Question: "This is question 2", Answers: "This is answer 2"),

        Question(Question: "This is question 1", Answers: "This is answer 1"),

    ]
    pickQuestion()
}


func pickQuestion() {

    if Questions.count > 0 {

        //setting Qnumber equal to 0 gives sequential quiz game no repeats
        QNumber = 0

        labelForQuestion.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
        textBoxForAnswer.text = Questions[QNumber].Answers

        //remove question so it doesnt come up again
        Questions.removeAtIndex(QNumber)
    }
}


@IBAction func Next(sender: AnyObject) {
    pickQuestion()
}


@IBAction func showAnswer(sender: AnyObject) {
    textBoxForAnswer.hidden = false
}
```

So basically I want to make `UIActions` that will enabled me to flick forward and backward between the questions. Any Ideas about how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `QNumber = 0` from `pickQuestion` and increment / decrement it outside. Additionally you probably should drop the `Questions.removeAtIndex(QNumber)`. Overall the changes should be:

specify the initial `QNumber` value

```
var QNumber : Int = 0
```

change the `pickQuestion` logic:

```
func pickQuestion() {
    labelForQuestion.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
    textBoxForAnswer.text = Questions[QNumber].Answers
}
```

Change the `Next`:

```
@IBAction func Next(sender: AnyObject) {
    QNumber++; // you need some handling to not go out of bounds if you are already showing the last question
    pickQuestion()
}
```

Same goes for the `previous(...)` doing a `QNumber--`.

Further notes:

- please let methods and variables start with lowercase letters: `next`, `qNumber`, `questions`, the members of each `question`, etc.

Comment: That is brilliant. Thanks for the help man exactly what I was looking for. I was able to throw in a little bit of code  that stopped it going out of bounds as well so its working perfectly now.